# Alternative to the HTML Bold tag

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I know that in HTML you can use the `<b>` tag, but isn't there a `"weight=bold"` attribute that I can use in the `<p>` tag?

Or is that in CSS, or Javascript?

Comment: I am starting a bounty on this question to promote it's visibility because I consider the top answer to be practically disastrous despite being technically correct.  Especially on a question that is very high in results for a google search for "bold tag in html5".

Comment: I vote this bounty ridiculous.  @mipadi has the correct answer.  If a user can't figure out that maybe they want to style something other than `p` then that is their own issue.  Maybe they'll ask a different SO question that will clear that up.

Answer (score 100):

Also consider the `<strong>` tag. It's much better for screen readers and therefore better for accessibility. Search engines also use `<strong>` tags to determine important content similar to how they use header tags `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc (although `<b>` will also have similar meaning to search engines). If you want to stress importance of text, use `<strong>`. If you *don't* want to stress importance, use the `<b>` tag or use the `font-weight:bold;` style on the element or in the CSS.

Although, if you are bolding the entire paragraph, it's probably better to use the CSS option. This will reduce the affect on screen readers and it probably doesn't make sense to have an entire paragraph emphasized. But on the other hand, I've seen bold used to emphasize an entire paragraph before for good reason. In which case, `font-weight:bold;` is what you want to use, likely in a class/style.

In the end, `<strong>`, `<b>` or `font-weight:bold;` will all work and accomplish something similar visually (probably exactly the same), but they have slightly different meanings. Also, make sure that if what you're bolding is a header, use the header tags: `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.

Comment: <b> is NOT deprecated in any current HTML or XHTML standard, nor is it deprecated even in the upcoming HTML 5.  <b> and <strong> have distinct meanings; <b> means "bold styled text".  <strong> means "stronger emphasis", but does not dictate a text style; browsers default to bold.

Comment: The widespread use of <b> has dwindled, but the actual element hasn't been deprecated according to the W3C specs.

Comment: The <b> is effectively deprecated in HTML5...and replaced with another <b> tag that has a somewhat different meaning. It's a weird choice, but that's basically what they've done. At any rate, it shouldn't be used to style text as bold.

Comment: @Chuck: what does the new b element mean ?

Comment: Per the draft spec: It indicates "a span of text to be stylistically offset from the normal prose without conveying any extra importance" — like keywords that might be bolded in marketing material. Basically, it's an attempt to give the <b> tag a *meaning* that doesn't conflict with current use.

Comment: I've started a bounty on this question to try to make it better, feel free to improve your answer if you're willing to do so.

Comment: Here is some more information on @Chuck's comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348683/will-the-b-and-i-tags-ever-become-deprecated/1743614#1743614

Comment: @Tchalvak thanks, hopefully the bounty does what you hope it does. I've tweaked the answer a bit to add more info. I hope I didn't add anything that's wrong.

Comment: Note that modern screen readers (such as latest versions of JAWS and Window Eyes) do not convey the contents of <em> or <strong> elements any differently in normal settings. A user must go into Proofreading mode for the speech output to be affected. Good reading: [Screen readers lack emphasis](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2008/02/screen-readers-lack-emphasis/) and [i, b, em and strong elements in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/).

Answer (score 79):

You're thinking of the CSS property `font-weight`:

```
p { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: Well, hopefully he doesn't copy what you have exactly...would mess a few things up :)

Comment: It's a syntactically-correct example. The OP will have to decide just _how_ he wants it to be used.

Comment: "Correct syntax" isn't everything, I wish this answer answer was better, as the top answer for a question with a lot of visibility in the quest for the solution to the b tag.  It's not promoting a good result, both because it's advocating styling of an element that has other much more important uses (paragraphing in text in general), and because it's advocating using a css style over cleaner alternatives like <strong>, <h1>, <em>, and <mark>.
It is technically workable, but practically, it invites disaster.

Comment: I've started a bounty on this question to try to make it better, feel free to improve your answer if you're willing to do so.

Comment: @Tchalvak: I'm using `<p>` as an example, because the OP used it as an example. `font-weight` works on any element, though.

Comment: @mipadi I understand that, but personally if a stranger asks me for "a really sharp knife to shave his face" I'm going to ignore the specific terminology of the request and give him a safety razor.

Comment: Available font-weights per/CSS2.0 specifications: normal | bold | bolder | lighter | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900 | inherit (CSS1.0 had all but inherit). http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-boldness. The answer matches the specs perfectly. It's just hard for most of us to see a global declaration like this being used in a real life setting. Not to speak for anyone, but the answer feels a lot like this: `* { margin:0; }` - viable, correct, a no-no.

Comment: Relevant only to the age of the `<b>` tag - had to share (circa 1993), and also from W3C: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt. When I started writing HTML in '98, `b` meant bold, `i` meant italic, and that was that...what other tags could someone possibly need, right?

Answer (score 23):

If the text's meaning is semantically *strong*, use the `strong` element. If not, use a semantic named class (one that clearly shows the meaning of the element, don't mix presentation and data by calling it `bold` etc) and reference it in your CSS.

#### HTML

```
<span class="important-message">I'm important!</span>
```

#### CSS

```
.important-message {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Some people still use the `b` element as a presentational hook, but it [hasn't been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html), though most people favour the `strong` element nowadays. Just make sure they are used correctly.

Comment: <b> is NOT deprecated.  It is still supported in HTML 4.01, XHTML 1, XHTML 1.1, and even the upcoming HTML 5.  Its deprecation is a myth.  Whether it *should* be deprecated is another matter.  It isn't.  See also http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html

Comment: Small technicality: a class name cannot be called 'semantic' because it is not a controlled vocabulary: there is no standard anywhere that defines what "important-message" means across apps. Naming your classes by their function is still a good idea because it promotes readability and best practice.

Comment: @thomasrutter... That's why I said *think*. A name doesn't have to be semantic only to computers; people read html too.

Answer (score 10):

The **<b>** tag is alive and well. <b> is not deprecated, but its use has been clarified and limited. <b> has no semantic meaning, nor does it convey vocal emphasis such as might be spoken by a screen reader. <b> does, however, convey *printed empasis*, as does the <i> tag. Both have a specific place in typograpghy, but not in spoken communication, *mes frères*.

**To quote from http://www.whatwg.org/**

> The b element represents a span of text to be stylistically offset from the normal prose without conveying any extra importance, such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, or other spans of text whose typical typographic presentation is boldened.

Answer (score 8):

You can make text or words `Bold` with using `<b>Text</b>` tag.

You can also use `<strong>Text</strong>` tag

Head tags `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, ... are default bolded tags and make your text Bold by default unless you change their style with CSS

Above tags was available in HTML but if you like to change the style with `CSS` you can use

```
font-weight:bold
```

Answer (score 7):

Its in CSS you have to set `font-weight: bold;` as style

Answer (score 7):

You can code like below..

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
 p.boldstats{
 font-weight: bold
  }
  </style>
 </head>

  <body>
  <p class="boldstats"> The bold finder </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the font-weight attribute on your

For example:

```
<p>This is my paragraph</p>
```

You can either have your CSS inline as below:

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;">This is my paragraph</p>
```

Or have it in your external CSS stylesheet as below:

```
p{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's all historical and dates from a time where dinosaurs walked the earth and CSS didn't exist.

More seriously, forget about the `<b/>` tag and use `font-weight:bold` in a CSS rule :)

Answer (score 4):

you could also do `<p style="font-weight:bold;"> bold text here </p>`

Comment: inline styles are about to be deprecated in html 5 :P

Comment: Are you sure? i thought only inline style tags were to be deprecated, ie. (big,s,strike,tt,u)

Comment: Even if they're not deprecated, they're almost always a bad idea. You might as well go back to using <font> tags.

Comment: inline styles are still suggested for small css files. Check Yslow and Google's PageSpeed. That's weird but sounds reasonable (fewer calls?)

Comment: @Kzqai: I agree 100%. For my specific case, I have to get rid of any inline styling due to heavy loading of an ajax request on a div. Just by removing any inline styling, it saves me some milliseconds on loading time.

Answer (score 4):

### `<b>` is a last resort

You can use `<b>`, but only as a **last resort**.  There are a variety of elements that work as good alternatives to `<b>`, here they are in order of most usefulness:

### More useful alternatives

- For important text: `<strong>`
- For stress emphasized text: `<em>`
- For headings, not just page headings but paragraph headings and others of all kinds: `<h1> through <h6>`

### The practical edge case for use of `<b>`

The only case where I would advocate using `<b>` is if

1. you have styled `<strong>` in a different way that you don't want displaying for the text that you have in mind,
2. you don't want *italic emphasis* or a heading, and
3. you are about to use an inline span or a span with a class just for **bolding text**.  (For example: `<span class='bold'>`)

Then it's reasonable to use `<b>` instead, because in that case it'll probably be cleaner/shorter and more semantic than an unsemantic span, and terceness/readability is a good reason for making that choice, since b has been redefined for use as an element denoting **printed emphasis**.

Answer (score 2):

```css
    #bold{
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #custom{
      font-weight: 200;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="bold"> here is a bold text using css </p>
  <p id="custom"> here is a custom bold text using css </p>
</body>
```

I hope it's worked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use CSS classes?

```
p.bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

That way you can still use `<p>` as normal.

```
<p>This is normal text</p>
<p class="bold">This is bold text</p>
```

Gives you:

This is normal text.

**This is Bold Text.**

Answer (score 1):

A very old thread, I know. - but for completeness:

I use `<span class="bold">my text</span>`

as I upload the four font styles: normal; bold; italic and bold italic into my web-site via css.

I feel the resulting output is better than simply modifying a font and is closer to the designers intention of how the boldened font should look.

The same applies for italic and bolditalic of course, which gives me additional flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

What you use instead of the `b` element depends on the semantics of that element's content.

- The elements `b` and `strong` have co-existed for a long time by now. In [HTML 4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-STRONG), which has been superseded by HTML5, `strong` was meant to be used for "strong emphasis", i.e. stronger emphasis than the `em` element (which just indicated emphasis). In [HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-strong-element), `strong` "represents strong importance, seriousness, or urgency for its contents"; the aspects of "seriousness" and "urgency" are new in the specification compared to HTML 4.01. So if you used `b` to represent content that was important, serious or urgent, it is recommended that you use `strong` instead. If you want, you can differentiate between these different semantics by adding meaningful class attributes, e.g. `<strong class="urgent">...</strong>` and `<strong class="warning">...</strong>` and use appropriate CSS selectors to style these types of "emphasis" different, e.g. using different colours and font sizes (e.g. in your CSS file: `strong.warning { color: red; background-color: transparent; border: 2px solid red; }`.). 

  Another alternative to `b` is the [`em` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-em-element), which in HTML 5.2 "represents stress emphasis of its contents". Note that this element is usually rendered in italics (and has therefore often been recommended as a replacement for the `i` element). 

  I would resist the temptation to follow the advice from some of the other answers to write something like `<strong class="bold">...</strong>`. Firstly, the class attribute doesn't mean anything in non-visual contexts (listening to an ePub book, text to speech generally, screen readers, Braille); secondly, people maintaining the code will need to read the actual content to figure out *why* something was bolded.
- If you used `b` for entire paragraphs or headings (as opposed to shorter spans of texts, which is the use case in the previous bullet point), I would replace it with appropriate `class` attributes or, if applicable, [WAI-ARIA roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) such as `alert` for a live region "with important, and usually time-sensitive, information". As mentioned above, you should use "semantic" `class` attribute values, so that people maintaining the code (including your future self) can figure out *why* something was bolded.
- Not all uses of the `b` may represent something semantic. For example, when you are converting printed documents into HTML, text may be bolded for reasons that have nothing to do with emphasis or importance but as a visual guide. For example, the headwords in dictionaries aren't any more "serious", "urgent" than the other content, so you may keep the `b` element and optionallly add a meaningful class attribute, e.g. `<b class="headword">` or replace the tag with `<span class="headword">` based on the argument that `b` has no meaning in non-visual contexts.

In your CSS file (instead of using `style` attributes, as some of the other answers have recommended), you have several options for styling the "bold" or important text:

- specifying different colours (foreground and/or background);
- specifying different font faces;
- specifying borders (see example above);
- using different font weights using the [**`font-weight` property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-weight-prop), which allows more values than just `normal` and `bold`, namely `normal | bold | bolder | lighter | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900`,
- etc.

Note that [support for numeric font-weight values](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_font-weight_number) has not always been great.

Answer (score 0):

On a sidenote the below code will also make it bold.

```
<strong> text here </strong>
```

Comment: ... in most browsers ... but only as a side effect of describing the text as having stronger emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following :

```
<p id="p1">Some Text here </p>
#p1{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

OR

```
<Strong><p>Some text here </p></strong>
```

OR

You can use `<h1> tag` which is somewhat similar to bold

Comment: Since p is probably block level, you'd want strong to go inside p.

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays people tend to use website builders (CMS like Wordpress) instead of coding their own blog from scratch. Even professional web developers do it because it's faster.

It would be nice if you could mention the advantages and things to keep in mind when coding your own blog in real life, for example:

- More flexibility (customization)
- Pay a domain name
- Pay and choose a web hosting
- Security and maintenance
- Copyright and license of some website builders' templates and graphics. Your website could be locked to a particular web host if you used your host's website builder. So you cannot move to another web host, because if you do you could no longer use that template.
- Experience trouble when asking for website builder's tech support when the website goes down.
- Some templates are not search engine friendly and this affects your website ranking (SEO)

Anyways, you can use css/css3 or JavaScript for making interactive webpage. Even you can upload your all sort of code into a server formatting the default blog theme.

Answer (score -2):

The answer by @Darryl Hein is correct despite one point - `<b>` is not recommended at all since XHTML, because it's not *semantic*.

`<strong>` means semantically highlighted text

`font-weight: bold` means visually highlighted text

`<strong>` can be css-tuned to not be bold, though it's a conventional default. It can be made red, or italic, or underlined (though all these possibilities are not really user-friendly). Use it for phrases / words in text, not because of visual design, but related to their meaning

`font-weight: bold` should be used for design-related bold parts, like headers, sub-headers, table header cells etc.

Comment: I don't believe that is true in the revised defintion for <b> in html5.

Comment: At the same time you on your own wrote that `<b>` is the last resort, and I wrote that b is not recommended. Where's the contradiction?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific in that I meant that it has a retconned semantic meaning in html 5: `...previous versions of HTML defined the b element only in presentational terms, the element has now been given the specific semantic purpose of representing text “offset from its surrounding content without conveying any extra emphasis or importance, and [conventionally boldened]”.` in html5, as per http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/b.html#b.  That is the reason that I consider `<b>` to be: valid/a last resort/wasn't semantic/is redefined to be semantic, etc. Just a subtle difference.

Answer (score -3):

Use the `<strong>` tag because it's more semantic. `<b>` has been depreciated so it's best not to use it. Also bold text is given more Search Engine Optimisation (SEO) weight so it's always best to use a real `<strong>` rather than making a `<p>` or `<span>` bold using CSS.

Comment: Don't use things because they are "more semantic" - use them because they have the semantics that apply to what you are writing. We don't know what the semantics of the text the OP has are.