# Will the <b> and <i> tags ever become deprecated?

Tags: html, tags, deprecated

(This is more of a curiousity question than any pending disaster :D )

So the `<b> and <i>` tags have been around since near the beginning of the web (I assume). But now we have CSS and many people apposing "stylistic html tags." They are stylistic tags, but they're really not so bad, as they save us from having to make a `<span class="bold">` a whole bunch of times, reducing download times. Seeing as they don't take up much space, are easy to use, can possibly be useful to screen-readers, search engines, and other applications that don't care much about how a document looks, and removing them would break TONS of html code, I'm guessing probably not, but I still wanted to bring up the topic. :)

Comment: As soon as there is **ONE** (X)HTML standard (singular!) and all browsers support it **FULLY** - yes :-) Don't hold your breath, though......

Comment: deprecated against _what_ specification?

Comment: Just looking at the source of your post, it appears SO uses <em> and <strong>.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing <em>any</em> documentation where they are deprecated.  HTML or XHTML, strict or transitional.

Comment: it is unfortunate that this question got closed as duplicate, because it seems to have a more correct and elaborate answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743497/are-i-and-b-tags-actually-deprecated/1743614#1743614 > than the original question. therefore voting to reopen.

Comment: looks like the duplicate got merged into this one, including my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348683/will-the-b-and-i-tags-ever-become-deprecated/1743614#1743614 . thank you!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you end up doing `<span class="bold">` a lot you are not correctly using either `span`, nor `class` names. Class names should tell you what the tag **is**, not what it **looks like**.

The correct replacement for `<b>` and `<i>` are `<strong>` and `<em>`, and they should be used to note that the specific text inside has a different *meaning* than the surrounding text.

**Update**: New specification for `<b>`, `<i>`,`<strong>`,`<em>` released under HTML 5

In HTML5 `<b>` and `<i>` have specific meaning as do `<strong>` and `<em>`. Use them all as specified.

[4.6.2 The ***em*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element) :

> The em element represents stress emphasis of its contents.

[4.6.3 The ***strong*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element):

> The strong element represents strong importance, seriousness, or urgency for its contents.

[4.6.16 The ***i*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element):

> The i element represents [...] otherwise offset from the normal prose [...], such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, [...].

[4.6.17 The ***b*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element):

> The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes [...], such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review [...].

Comment: +1 for bringing up markup relating to meaning instead of presentation.

Comment: <strong> is only a replacement for <b> where the author intends emphasis of a section of text, and <em> only a replacement for <i> when indicating where the stress in a sentence lies. For other purposes, such as employing typographical conventions like italicising a ship's name, using those tags would be completely wrong. HTML 5 encourages <i> for ship's names and the like. If the text is being made bold or italic for purely presentation reasons, (and we all like to make our web sites look nice) <span> with  appropriate categorizations in the class attribute is the correct form.

Comment: Actually, when I say <span> is the correct form, I mean use <span> or <div> in the absence of a more semantic element in the specific context of the text on the page. What matters is the categorization, which can then be styled with CSS.

Comment: @Alohci: I agree with you that, when lacking a semantic element, you should use `<span>` or `<div>`, but generally they are overabused, and used in place of perfectly semantic tags.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it doesn't address the title which asks whether or not `<i>` and `<b>` are deprecated.

Comment: @AlexW, to clarify, no <i> and <b> tags are NOT deprecated.  Neither in the HTML4 or HTML5 standards. You can see a table of all tags for the HTML4 standard along with their status here http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html.  For the HTML5 working standard you can look here for text level semantics. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element

Comment: Good info but I down-voted because it doesn't get to the point of the question

Comment: Incorrect, the <strong> and <em> tags are not meant to replace <b> and <i>. <strong> is meant for a text that you want to strongly highlight, it could be with bold letters or something else, but that is defined in your own css styles. <em> is meant for texts to do emphasis, by default is an italic text, but it can be given style for something else.

It is also incorrect to say that css classes are to specify what the tag is, the tag is what it is, the class is to give it style

Comment: @JuanCarlosDiaz: _It is also incorrect to say that css classes are to specify what the tag is, the tag is what it is, the class is to give it style._ A class name `asdf` can be used to style with CSS, but it conveys no meaning. A class name `user-menu` can also be styled with CSS, and at the same time conveys what the element is or contains.

Comment: So, according to your answer, Bootstrap is all wrong.

Answer (score 61):

They are [not deprecated in HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.1), and they [won't be deprecated in HTML 5](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/main/FAQ.md#why-are-some-presentational-elements-like-b-i-and-small-still-included). For reasons:

> The inclusion of those elements is a largely pragmatic decision based
> upon their widespread usage, and their utility for cases which are not
> covered by more-specific elements.
>
> While there are a number of common use cases for italics which are
> covered by more-specific elements, such as emphasis (`<em>`), citations
> (`<cite>`), definitions (`<dfn>`) and variables (`<var>`), there are many
> other use cases which are not covered well by these elements. For
> example: a taxonomic designation, a technical term, an idiomatic
> phrase from another language, a thought, or a ship name.
>
> Similarly, although a number of common use cases for bold text are
> also covered by more-specific elements, such as strong emphasis
> (`<strong>`), headings (`<h1>`-`<h6>`) or table headers (`<th>`), there are
> others which are not, such as keywords in a document abstract or
> product names in a review.
>
> Some people argue that in such cases, the `<span>` element should be
> used with an appropriate class name and associated stylesheet.
> However, the `<b>` and `<i>` elements provide for a reasonable fallback
> styling in environments that don't support stylesheets or which do not
> render visually, such as screen readers, and they also provide some
> indication that the text is somehow distinct from its surrounding
> content.
>
> In essence, the `<i>` and `<b>` elements convey distinct, though
> non-specific, semantics, which are to be determined by the reader in
> the context of their use. In other words, although they don't convey
> specific semantics by themselves, but instead they indicate that the
> content is somehow semantically distinct from its surroundings —
> leaving the interpretation of the semantics up to the reader.
>
> This is further explained in the article [The `<b>` and `<i>` Elements](https://lachy.id.au/log/2007/05/b-and-i).
>
> Similarly, the `<small>` element is defined for content that is commonly
> typographically rendered in small print, and which is often referred
> to as "fine print"; that could include copyright statements,
> disclaimers and other legal text commonly found at the end of a
> document.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know.  A lot of good answers, this is the best. Thanks to everyone for responding.

Comment: IMHO, this reply answers the OP's question directly, and should have been accepted as the solution.

Answer (score 9):

No. `<i>` and `<b>` are not deprecated, at least not [in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.1). One situation in which they may apply would be a list of references. For example, in Germany references are given in the following way:

> Author: *Title.* Publisher, Year, ...

In this case the title is defined to be italic. It's no special emphasis (as would be signified by the `<em>` tag) but really italic.

**ETA:** And yes, you should use the `<cite>` element as well. But my point still stands:

```
<cite>Author: <i>Title.</i> ...</cite>
```

Wikipedia also uses both tags extensively, last time I looked.

Comment: No, in that case the appropriate element would be cite.

Comment: ... which still doesn't ensure that it renders correctly. Sure, an in-line reference to some source would be a good use for `cite`, a single reference in a reference list as well. But for making a substring italic *within* the citation? Correct me if I'm wrong, but last time I looked, not even CSS letz me do that. Remember that it's only the title which gets italicized.

Answer (score 8):

`b` and `i` have no semantical meaning. If you want just bold text, use b, but any other cases you should use `strong` and `em`

Comment: Yeah, but "Are “<i>” and “<b>” tags actually deprecated?" I'd assume HTML 4 since 5 isn't ready yet.

Comment: They are not depracated but not recommended to use as semantical tags.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the "separate style from presentation" guideline is to use `<em>` and `<strong>` instead of `<i>` and `<b>`, no `<span>` required.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html they are not currently deprecated.

Comment: It also has relatively NOT been surpassed. For example, see the work on HTML5.

Comment: Note that XHTML only defines a syntax and refers to HTML4 for semantics.

Answer (score 4):

Great question, and I'd suggest that:

YES, they SHOULD be deprecated. They're a styling tag, and add no content.

No, they WON'T be deprecated because they're so ingrained that it'd be a nightmare to take out.

That said, very likely that all browsers would continue to support the `<b>` and `<i>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the IE-6 browser folks!!
This browser has partly problems with the <strong> tag when it is used inside the caption of an <a></a> tag.
example:
<a><strong>Hello</strong></a>
The IE-6 creates a linebreak at the screen before the opening <strong> tag and after the closing </strong> tag.
Not so by using the <b>(bold) tag instead. Everything is shown correctly then.

regards, Matthias

Answer (score 2):

1. They are non-semantic, and tread on CSS' toes.
2. No, too many people like quick, dirty methods too much.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very much whether browsers would drop support for them. However, if the W3C validater raises an error for pages utilising them then I feel, over time, there use will depreciate. It takes time, but people do change habits - look at the once ubiquitous FONT tag, for instance.

Comment: This might be because there are obviously better ways of doing things than the font tag - CSS works so well now you don't need the font tag any more. However, using <strong> has no advantages of <b>, so <b> will probably stick around longer.

Comment: The fact that `<font>` is used less and less each day, doesn't mean that we don't see things like `<span class="italics">My text is <span class="bold">great!</span></span>`, that is equally nefarious. Not everyone on the internet *gets CSS*. As a matter of fact, a great percentage of the web has been made with **MS Word**.

Answer (score 1):

`<b>` and `<i>` are not structural or semantic elements. You want your HTML to be semantic/structural and your CSS to contain the styling.

See [here](http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=222) or [here](http://jasongraphix.com/journal/bold-strong-italic-emphasis/)

Answer (score 0):

In XHTML 2.0 they are. I'm not sure about HTML 6 (if that ever comes), but I think it will. But it's really useless to think about it right now, since in 2130 the same browsers must still work and the nowadays website must still be available for anyone then. You can always change it later using javascript or something.

Comment: XMTML 2.0 seems to be doing friends with the Dodo, even before it got off the ground http://www.webmonkey.com/blog/XHTML_2_Dies_a_Lonely_Death__Makes_Room_For_HTML_5

Answer (score 0):

You can see it as tags which have "by coincidence" the same default styles as `<b>` and `<i>`. You should not see it as an exact replacement of `<b>` and `<i>`, but you should use it whenever the **content** has actually a semantically *strong* or *emphasized* meaning. You're however free to style it further to your taste.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is old but posting this info for future references and updating purpose

In HTML5 `<b>` and `<i>` have specific meaning as do `<strong>` and `<em>`. Use them all as specified.

4.6.2 The ***em*** element 
[WHATWG.org...]

> www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element

4.6.3 The ***strong*** element 
[WHATWG.org...]

> www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element

4.6.16 The ***i*** element 
[WHATWG.org...]

> www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element

4.6.17 The ***b*** element 
[WHATWG.org...]

> www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element

Answer (score -4):

if they become deprecated, the name "HTML" as is (hypertext **markup language**) would become senseless. as it wouldn't be the html-code marking some text as bold but it would be the CSS.

in my opinion: no, they don't get deprecated too soon...

regards

Comment: That is what `<strong>` and `<em>` are for. You don't say *this is bold*, but rather you say *this is emphasized*

Comment: So any markup language in which you can't specify that text is to be set in bold type is senseless? That seems pretty senseless to me.

Comment: @Chuck: not any. html. bold was an example. well in fact you may see it how you want it. one way is to say we mark up the format (example bold, italic) or we mark up the logical content of a document (example em, etc). guess it's a question of the definition of the abbreviation "html".

in my opinion i think it's not good to deprecate formatting tags.

Comment: @voyager: Shouldn't that be "this is italicized" rather than "this is bold" for "this is emphasized"?