# Use Greasemonkey to add bold tags to dates on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that prints a div -- works! However, I'd like to be able to add bold tags to all dates in this div.

Dates are formatted MM/DD/YYYY

So something like:

```
var regex = '\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}';
```

Then how would I perform the search replace? If the div was called `loanTable`:

Non-working concept:

```
$("#loanTable").html().replace( regex, "<b>" regex "</b>" )
```

Something like the above should work but I'm not sure of the exact syntax for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regex capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html):

```
var loanTable   = $("#loanTable")
var loanHTML    = loanTable.html ().replace (/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/g, "<b>$1</b>");
loanTable.html (loanHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is not valid JS:

```
var regex = '\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}';
$("#loanTable").html().replace( regex, "<b>" regex "</b>" )
```

The syntax for regex is `/regex/`, non quoted, or `new Regex('regex')` with quotes.

Start by assigning the html to a variable. Also `<b>` is barely used anymore, `<strong>` is the new standard. Then, `replace()` takes a regex and a string or function as parameters. To replace multiple times you have to use the `g` flag. Finally, to do what you want to accomplish you can use replacement tokens, like `$1` etc...

```
var re = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/g; // 'g' flag for 'global';
var html = $("#loanTable").html();

$("#loanTable").html(html.replace(re, '<strong>$&</strong>')); // The `$&` token returns the whole match
```

Comment: "`<b>` is barely... `<strong>` is the new standard." WHAT?!? The two are completely different. `<b>` is a formatting tag used to BOLD something. `<strong>` is an informational tag telling the user agent to show it to the user differently. Coincidentally, many standard browsers render strong tags as bold. TTS software will usually speak bold tags normally but put an emphasis on strong tags (if they do).

Comment: See solution to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348683/will-the-b-and-i-tags-ever-become-deprecated

Comment: "<strong> is only a replacement for <b> where the author intends emphasis of a section of text, and <em> only a replacement for <i> when indicating where the stress in a sentence lies. For other purposes, such as employing typographical conventions like italicising a ship's name, using those tags would be completely wrong. HTML 5 encourages <i> for ship's names and the like. If the text is being made bold or italic for purely presentation reasons, (and we all like to make our web sites look nice) <span> with appropriate categorizations in the class attribute is the correct form."

Answer (score 1):

Last time I used GreaseMonkey, it wasn't easy to get jQuery to run in your user scripts.

Use the following code to do it without jQuery:

```
var loanTable = document.getElementById('loanTable');
loanTable.innerHTML = loanTable.innerHTML.replace(/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Comment: +1 for POJS, but fails in IE because you can't set the innerHTML of a table.

Comment: jQuery is not the issue here; it is not hard at all to use jQuery in a userscript; and "ScriptMonkey" is either off topic or inappropriate.

Comment: @BrockAdams—why so harsh? There is absolutly no reason to use jQuery for something so trivial.

Comment: @RobG, I wasn't harsh.  Nor was I bothered about the non-use of jQuery; that would have got an upvote, if it ended there.  I was pointing out the falsehood about jQuery use, and also questioning an inappropriate term.  Also, note that the OP started out not using jQuery for this, and then claimed that it started working after he switched (See his previous Q's).

Comment: @BrockAdams Ouch. ScriptMonkey was a typo... I meant GreaseMonkey. And last time I tried to use jQuery in a userscript it was hard. Things might have changed but I would **prefer to use two lines of POJS** rather than writing it in **two jQuery lines and bring in a 3rd party library** using the following approach or similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome

Comment: @RobG Thanks :-) I see your point but I think the id is misleading because the question states that he's using a div.

Answer (score 0):

One small aspect of this: you need to concatenate strings with a `+` operator:

```
$("#loanTable").html().replace( regex, "<b>" + regex + "</b>" )
```