# JQuery / JS variable to alert text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#output').html("<strong>id:</strong>"+id);
```

then

```
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>
```

The above works fine but what I need is for the output to go into an alert so....

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('OUTPUT GOES HERE')">Alert Me</a>  <- See here
```

How can this be done?

Comment: FYI `<b>` will be deprecated

Comment: @banzsh - can you document that claim ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the html to be visible in the alert

Comment: @banzsh: That is incorrect.  See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1743614/116614) to [Will the <b> and <i> tags ever become deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348683/will-the-b-and-i-tags-ever-become-deprecated)

Comment: I may be wrong but quite sure I read it on w3c spec that cannot find now. However I'd like styling to be exclusively in stylesheet than html and stylesheet :) Cheers

Comment: I'm only using <b> for testing. I would normally use <strong> or css font-weight:bold;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the anchor some type of `id` or attribute that can be used to look it up:

```html
<a href="#" id="alertOutput">Alert Me</a>
```

Then bind to its click event to alert the text content of the `#output` element:

```js
$("#alertOutput").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( $("#output").text() );
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` portion will prevent the page from jumping back to the top of the document when the anchor is clicked.

Comment: Ha! We had the same answer :P

Comment: @Chad Genius minds think alike, and it was a fairly basic question :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I exactly understand what you are asking, bind the click event instead of the `onclick` attribute.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="alertAnchor">Alert Me</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#alertAnchor').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('#output').text());
});
```

Hope this helps, if you clarify what you are looking for I can edit.

Answer (score 1):

or if you are lazy and want a quick fix:

```
<a href="#" onclick="e.preventDefault(); alert($('#output').html())">Alert Me</a>  <- See here
```