# What are the current standards regarding using <b> and <I> tags?

Tags: html, coding-style, standards

As I understand it, formatting is expected to be done with CSS, not tags like `<b>` and `<i>`. However, these tags are still in widespread use, along with tags like `<em>` and `<strong>`. I understand that these tags have semantic value, but what is the current expectation (standard) regarding their use, especially in HTML5?

Comment: I would do it always with CSS. Due to HTML5 can use "custom" tags. See here: http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate post. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348683/will-the-b-and-i-tags-ever-become-deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348683/will-the-b-and-i-tags-ever-become-deprecated) nonetheless this is a good link.

Answer (score 2):

Not a duplicate in my eyes.  The question is specific about their semantic values in HTML5.

1. There are now two set of HTML5 standards - [The living standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) by
   [whatwg](http://www.whatwg.org/), and the the [w3c standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). They are not necessary the same.  Fortunately, for this question they are.
2. As of 2014 Apr, [both](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) [specify](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) that `<i>` means "alternate voice or mood", and `<b>` means "conveying extra importance".  So they can be safely used to represent these semantic meanings.  Please note that the semantic meanings are not exactly the same with `<em>` or `<strong>`, despite that all browsers I know apply the same default styles.
3. When client/users says "Please bold these words" you rarely (if ever) ask them whether they mean "extra importance" or "seriousness/urgency" or actually "stress emphasis", and for good reasons.  Since almost everyone use them the same way, using them for quick styling for a few words and not worring about standard is ok and saves everyone's time.  It's when you apply them en masse (e.g. for every menu item, for every navigation link, etc) that it should be frowned upon.

Comment: Interesting point. It's nice to see that the SO community keeps such a careful watch

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a sort of unwritten standard people follow to not use b and i tags anymore, at least not as they have been in the past. To a lesser extent the same seems true for em and strong. Honestly, between something like the `<strong>` tag and CSS, I think it's personal preference.

I don't know of any real standard here. All the tags in question have use.

Supposedly screen readers may also be able to provide more information with strong and em tags, which perhaps gives them more credibility. Though in practice I'm not sure how often that's actually the case.

Interesting aside: Viewing the source of this page, you can see that the `<b>` tag is being used right here on SO.