# For visual purposes why is there a strong and bold html tag?

Tags: html, css

Been doing html dev for 15 years and manage a ton of sites.  These tags functionally do the same thing to words.  I can style each similar in css.  I have even found uses for strong and bold by doing stuff like making strong show block lettering or a different color... but really I could have added a class for that.  Why do these exist?  How can I explain this to a new coworker learning html beyond "It's just another whacky/stupid thing you have to deal with and they are in effect the same thing?"

There is already a question- What's the difference between `<b>` and `<strong>`, `<i>` and `<em>`?   - This question is too old and references and answers are made using old html/css standards that no longer apply.

But this question has an answer that has 425 vote ups that is more or less marred with mistakes.  B and strong are not styles and are just tags that can be styles.  I understand the aspect of handicap reading but that didn't need a new formatting tag to accomplish that.

Comment: @MarinaDunst - I believe my question is slightly different and the answers are in a sense wrong.   I am wondering why from a visual angle we have two tags that do the exact same thing and have the exact same editable css properties...  This actually comes from a colleague of mine that I am teaching html.  I had no answer for them, nor did that question help them - it is answered wrong.

Comment: @user2864740 - Exactly.  I had a site where b was just red italicized and strong was bold at 80%.

Comment: @user2864740 - visually they do.

Comment: *Only* with the default style sheets in certain (well, probably most mainstream) browsers. There is no mandate that they are styled the same. The linked answer provides links to the HTML 5 LD definitions and the LD expands upon the styling requirements (or lack of).

Comment: @user2864740 - hmm maybe - but doesn't everyone reset their css now?

Comment: But the "reset css" is to *some default*, be it forced in the CSS reset itself or by the browsers default stylesheets. There is *no mandate* that b is styled as strong or em is styled as i, etc.

Comment: @user2864740 - so in essence you are supporting my question because you are saying that since there are two VERY similar tags different browsers have take the liberties of attaching default actions to them to make them unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72940/discussion-between-user2864740-and-blankip).

Comment: FWIW: I think it is best to *not* close this question as a duplicate unless there is a question *explicitly relating to the usage/distinction/visualization in HTML 5 with CSS* - remember that related questions can be linked and much has changed since 2008.

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 makes the distinction *semantic*, and not strictly visual as it was previously.

In HTML5 `<b>` and `<i>` have specific meaning as do `<strong>` and `<em>`. Use them all as specified.

[4.6.2 The ***em*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element) :

> The em element represents stress emphasis of its contents.

[4.6.3 The ***strong*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element):

> The strong element represents strong importance, seriousness, or urgency for its contents.

[4.6.16 The ***i*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element):

> The i element represents [...] otherwise offset from the normal prose [...], such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, [...].

[4.6.17 The ***b*** element](http://www.WHATWG.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element):

> The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes [...], such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review [...].

The HTML5 Living Standard goes on with this note *emphasising* that both B and I elements now live on in terms of semantic meaning, whereas in HTML4/pre-CSS they were very strongly associated with the display:

> Style sheets can be used to format b elements, just like any other element can be restyled. Thus, *it is not the case that content in b elements will necessarily be boldened.*

---

Following the guidelines given above,

Correct:

```html
It is <strong>important</strong> to empty the <b>Dyson</b> before it overfills.
The <i>Heterocephalus glaber</i> was <em>shivering</em> in the cold.
```

Incorrect:

```html
It is <b>important</b> to empty the <strong>Dyson</strong> before it overfills.
The <em>Heterocephalus glaber</em> was <i>shivering</i> in the cold.
```

---

The main content was taken directly from [this answer by voyager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348704/2864740) - which I think contains very relative information. However, the linked answer doesn't really answer the question to which it was an answer to, and is easy to miss due to the mismatched title.

Comment: So does this answer mean that they are the same thing or just that they have different definitions but do the same thing?   Why would the user know the difference between the Correct and Incorrect example at the bottom?  Would the open up chrome dev and be like "Ahh they weren't highlighting the word, they were emphasizing it!"

Comment: They represent *different* things. As to how much weight your team puts on using the more semantically correct element - or just making it 'look pretty' for the site visitor - is a policy decision. I urge for 'correct' even if nobody [else] will know. There are some ugly sites with beautiful markup and some beautiful sites with ugly markup. After all, one could replace all of the above with SPAN elements (with different classes) and style them to their hearts content .. there *may* be clients/programs that are more semantically-aware, but I don't deal with such.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference html strong vs bold, it is necessary to understand that the `<strong>` tag defines the importance of highlighted text, while the `<b>` tag is used to highlight text without the quality of importance.
An [example](https://domhtml.ru/en/tags-strong-b-html/) of a difference would be the OS settings used by the visually impaired. When text reading is turned on with the "speaker" functionality, words will be highlighted by the intonation of the `strong` tag. The situation is similar with the `<i>` and `<em>` tags. "Speaker" will highlight the em tag with intonation.

Answer (score -2):

difference ?
tag  just styling elements
tag  is semantic
in practice every browser just go a head and make it bold.
the short answer is. don't worry about it, as far as i know google
will tread the strong, the bold, is the same.