# How we can bold only the name in table td tag not the value

Tags: html, html-table

Is there any way that I can make CC Quid, Application Number, Application Title and in the same way other thing in bold, I don't want their value to be in bold. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

```
html = html + "<table border ='0'>";
    html= html + "<tr>";
    html =html + "<td>CC Quid: " +(data.response.docs[0].c_cc_guid)+"</td></tr>";
    html =html + "<tr><td>Application Number: " +(data.response.docs[0].c_application_number)+"</td></tr>";
    html =html + "<tr><td>Application Title: " +(data.response.docs[0].c_application_title)+"</td></tr>";
    html =html + "<tr><td>Application Type Name: " +(data.response.docs[0].c_application_type_name)+"</td></tr>";
    html =html + "<tr><td>Case Mgr Name: " +(data.response.docs[0].c_case_mgr_name)+"</td></tr>";
    html =html + "<tr><td>Filed Date: " +(data.response.docs[0].c_filed_date)+"</td></tr>";
    html =html + "<tr><td>Lead Atny Name: " +(data.response.docs[0].c_lead_atny_name)+"</td></tr>";
    html =html + "</table>";
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Surround what you want to be bold with:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">Your bold text</span>
```

This would go inside your `<td>` tag.

Comment: why not <td style="font-weight:bold">?

Comment: "How we can bold *only the name* in table td tag not the value"

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the name in a span, give it a class and assign a style to that class:

```
<td><span class="names">Name text you want bold</span> rest of your text</td>
```

style:

```
.names { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be misunderstanding your question, so apologies if I am.

If you're looking for the words "Quid", "Application Number", etc. to be bold, just wrap them in `<strong>` tags:

```
<strong>Quid</strong>: ...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `<strong>` isn't meant for that, if you _really_ want to use HTML then use `<b>`. [Here's a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649305/alternative-to-the-html-bold-tag).

Comment: Oh man....stuck writing HTML as a CRM architect at the moment...don't know why your not the accepted answer....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
td.setAttribute("style", "font-weight:bold");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.Bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<span> normal text</span> <br>
<span class="Bold"> bold text</span> <br>
<span> normal text</span> <spanspan>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use to table header tag below  for a text in a table to make it standout from the rest of the table content.

```
 <table>

    <tr>
     <th>Dimension:</th>
    <td>98cm x 71cm</td>
    </tr>
   </table
```